# Searching std::map in O(n) for a partial key

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

I have a (C++ 14) map

```
using MyTuple = tuple<A, B, C>;
map<MyTuple, MyData>
```

where `MyTuple` has the obvious `operator<()` that compares first A, then B, then C.

I want to do an `O(ln N)` search for keys that match some constant `(a, b)`.  Obviously if any are present they will be consecutive.  So basically I want

```
map<MyTuple, MyData> my_map = GetMyData();
tuple<A, B> my_key = make_tuple(a, b);
auto iter = my_map.lower_bound_if([my_key](const MyTuple& key) {
    if (get<0>(my_key) == get<0>(key) &&
        get<1>(my_key) == get<1>(key)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
while( /* iter.first is still an (a,b) */) {
    // Do something with iter.
    // Increment iter.
}
```

But there's no function `map::lower_bound_if` and yet `map::find` and `map::lower_bound` take a full `MyTuple`.  I could (hackishly) find a value of `C` that is lower than anything in my data, though this is fragile over time.  I could write the function myself though it would likely be dependent on my current local implementation of `std::map`.

Have I missed an obvious solution?

### Update

The solution, which I've accepted, was to use partial key mathing in the compare function (transparent operator functors), which are new since C++14 and took me longer than I care to admit to understand.  [This article](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/06/09/search-set-another-type-key/) was a good mental ice breaker and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737132/transparent-operator-functors) was good once I understood.

The basic insight is to consider a set of objects sorted on some key that is part of the object.  For example, a set of employees with the sort key being `employee.id`.  And we'd like to be able to search on employee or on the integer id.  So we make a struct of `bool operator()()` that encompasses the various ways we might want to compare.  And then overload resolution does the rest.

In my case, this meant that I could provide the strict total ordering I needed to make my code work but also provide a comparator that only imposes a partial ordering which I only use for `lower_bound()` lookups.  Because the extra comparator doesn't provide a strict total ordering, it would not be suitable for, say, `find()` unless we meant "find one of".

As an aside, I realised after posing my question that it was a bit daft in a way.  I wanted an `O(ln n)` lookup but wanted to use a different sort function.  That can't be guaranteed to work: it depends on me providing a sort function that really does provide an ordering that is a sub-ordering of the strict total ordering.  If I did otherwise, it would clearly fail.  And so this is why there's no `O(ln n)` function `find_if()`, because that can *only* be linear.

Indeed, the technique of transparent operator functors is clever but does depend on the programmer providing no worse than a subordering.

Comment: A `map` of `tuple<A, B>` to `map` of `C` to `MyData`?

Comment: I think you can use [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) with map. With it you can provide a custom comparer.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators

Comment: Are you sure you even want to do this? The standard library maps [are slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588384/1593077).

Comment: @einpoklum Probably I do this time, but that's really good reading, thanks.

Comment: [This question has been featured in a CppCon presentation!](https://youtu.be/9Tx97HeGnUQ?t=2967)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In c++14 you can use the overload to [search on a partial key](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/equal_range):

```
struct CompareFirstTwo {
    using is_transparent = void;
    bool operator()(const tuple<A, B, C>& lhs, const tuple<A, B, C>& rhs) const ...
    bool operator()(const tuple<A, B>& lhs, const tuple<A, B, C>& rhs) const ...
    bool operator()(const tuple<A, B, C>& lhs, const tuple<A, B>& rhs) const ...
};
```

Use the comparator above in a call to `equal_range` to ignore the third field in the tuple.

Comment: Do you mean that I should define the `std::map` with this comparator?  (I'd have to use a multimap, then.)  Other uses of the map want to distinguish different values of C.

Comment: Yes, you would have to define a map with this comparator, but you wouldn't need to make it a multimap, because the comparator can handle all legal combinations of 3-element vs. 2-element tuples.

Comment: This took me some work to understand merely because it wasn't what I expected.  For future readers, [this article](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/06/09/search-set-another-type-key/) helped break the ice.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to put "any value you like" for C, use lower_bound, and be aware that the values you are looking for might be before the lower_bound, as well as after, so you might need to do some operator-- to find the first one, just as you would use operator++ to find the last one? The number of operations in order to find the range in advance does not change, but there is an in-advance overhead if you wanted to iterate over them and test for the end of <A,B> on the fly.

Obviously, it would be convenient, but not necessary, if that C was a "hacky" value that compared as the lowest possible C, as that would make the backward search faster, but we have mitigated your risk of fragility?

Another option would be to make your own container that is a map of maps. The outer map would be indexed by <A,B> and the inner map indexed by < C >.

You could then add your own methods to implement a whole-map indexing and iteration using <A,B,C>; and use the existing <A,B> methods to either return the inner map when indexed, or return your iterators as results for lower_bound and upper_bound, that can then be used as a range for all <A,B,allC>.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an order such that `x {xa, xb, xc}` is always `<` than `y {ya, yb, yc}` when `f(xa, xb)` (and conversely for `>`), it becomes easy. Consider it as "sort by A and B first".

Then you just need to know your maximal and minimal `C` value.

Search between `lower_bound(a, b, MIN_C)` and `upper_bound(a, b, MAX_C)`. Alternatively, as suggested in the comments

> A map of tuple<A, B> to map of C to MyData? – Vlad Feinstein

would work.

Comment: Sadly, C does not provide an easy minimum value that I am sure will remain valid forever.  If it did, as noted in the question, this would be easier.